# ¿Cómo achicar un texto junto a una imagen responsive en CSS?

Tags: html, css, imagen, responsive

¿Cómo pongo un texto sobre una imagen responsive, que cuando la imagen se adapte a un tamaño más pequeño el texto también?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```css
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
 display: block;
 position: relative;  
}

/* Bottom right text */
.text-block {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 50px;
 right:100px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}
h10 {
 color: black;
 font: bold 16px/36px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
}
pp {
 color: white;
 font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a href="enviar.php" class="image featured">
  <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-6lLUfA4Jkig/Txk6NnOEF7I/AAAAAAAAACU/qLspTGYpRn4/s1600/imagen+original.JPG" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;" />
 </a> 
 <div class="text-block"> 
  <h10>Texto que quiero que se mueva.</h10>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola amigo hay varios metodos los mas seguros serian usar las medidas de la letra en base al (view port) units.

```
 .texto p {
   font-size: 3.5vw;
 }
```

O puedes usar la media de pantallas para definir el texto a medida que la pantalla se reduzca o expanda.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:300px){
  font-size: {12px}
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Espero Ayudar!

```css
.textoC {
    display: block;
    position: inherit;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    color: #000;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="text-block" style="
    position: absolute;
">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/374780/pexels-photo-374780.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=650&amp;w=940"
><span class="textoC">
    correo@dominio.com
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: poner respuestas que son solo código se considera de baja calidad, agrega una explicación